# Partial RESTful update url structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

Lets say I have a User object `/Users/1`. On my view, I have multiple partitions to edit this user, for eg. `Information`, `Contact`, `Location`. Which are in 3 seperate forms.

Im thinking about doing: `POST /Users/1?Part=Information`, `POST /Users/1?Part=Contact`, `POST /Users/1?Part=Location`. My server (asp.net mvc) would be the one to look at the `Part` Query param and adjust the user as stated.

Is this a good way to do partial updates? What other ways are there?

If using the HTTP PATCH is the best option, please explain it.

PS.

This [blog](http://intertwingly.net/blog/2008/02/15/Embrace-Extend-then-Innovate) says using query params are bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Information, Contact, etc, are structural components of the object, you could just use the natural URLs of:

```
/Users/1/Information
/Users/1/Location
...
```

Comment: In this case, is it ok to not have any POST on `Users/1`?

Comment: POST in the context of REST are used to convert the resource into a collection itself, but in this case, 1 is an object, so I don't think you need POST in that URL.

Comment: Yup, that's a possible solution.

Comment: “POST in the context of REST are used to convert the resource into a collection itself”  That was not my understanding.  Collections typically support POST, but any resource can support it.  Do you have more info?